# how to remove multiple line text from one word to other word

Tags: c#, regex, web-scraping

I'm scraping data off a web page into text file in that I want to remove some irrelevant content like

```html
    </h3>
    <div class="form clearfix">
      <a href="/matches/2012/11/11/mexico/primera-division/club-san-luis/deportivo-toluca-futbol-club/1292713/" class="form-icon form-loss " title="San Luis - Toluca 0 - 2">L</a>
      <a href="/matches/2012/11/04/mexico/primera-division/club-tijuana-xoloitzcuintles-de-caliente/club-san-luis/1292699/" class="form-icon form-draw " title="Tijuana - San Luis 0 - 0">D</a>
      <a href="/matches/2012/10/28/mexico/primera-division/club-san-luis/queretaro-fc/1292695/" class="form-icon form-draw " title="San Luis - Querétaro 0 - 0">D</a>
      <a href="/matches/2012/10/21/mexico/primera-division/club-atlas-de-guadalajara/club-san-luis/1292684/" class="form-icon form-win " title="Atlas - San Luis 2 - 3">W</a>
      <a href="/matches/2012/10/14/mexico/primera-division/club-san-luis/club-atlante/1292674/" class="form-icon form-draw last" title="San Luis - Atlante 2 - 2">D</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container middle">
    <h3 class="thick scoretime ">
```

I'm trying for output as `</h3><h3 class="thick scoretime ">` removing other data.

I tried

```
source = regax.replace(source, </h3>.*<h3 class="thick scoretime "> ","</h3><h3 class="thick scoretime "> ")
```

but it didn't work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you clarify your question. What specifically do you want to remove? You probably don't want to use RegEx. The RegEx you show is going to replace the entire file with a whitespace. You need some reasonable barriers, like if you want to remove all headers, I could tell you how to do that.

Comment: For manipulating a rendered DOM, you might want to use the HTML Agility Pack. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: @evanmcdonnal i want to remove all data from <div class to </div>

Comment: Alright, I have a simple RegEx.

Comment: @SteveWellens im confused with DOM and HAP so can u pls help?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal can u help me with Regex pls to get the output.

Comment: **"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems."** http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HTML Agilty Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - It is an open source *HTML parser* for .NET.

What is exactly the Html Agility Pack (HAP)?

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

You can use this to query HTML and extract whatever data you wish.

---

If it is ultimately required to extract the text based on Regex patterns as per your requirement, you can do it this way:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("</h3>(?<Junk>.*)<h3 class=\"thick scoretime \">",
    RegexOptions.None | RegexOptions.Singleline);
var extractedString = regex.Replace(htmlString, "${Junk}");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will search for all

```
 string file = "TheEntireFileIsInThisBuffer";
 string pattern = "<div.*</div>"; 
 RegEx rgx = new RegEx(pattern);
 string fileWithOutDivs = rgx.Replace(file, System.String.Empty);
```

Comment: what if my file have many div tags and i want to remove data between just one div tag?

Comment: @sam Then I'm gonna need some more information to identify the specific div you want to remove; is this going to be a one off solution or is it supposed to work with many web pages?

Comment: http://www.soccerway.com/matches/2012/10/06/spain/segunda-b/deportivo-alaves/real-sociedad-de-futbol-ii/338251/ from this page i am trying for information of event like  San Luis(hyperlink of this team) ~ 0-0~ tigers UANL(hyperlink of this)~competition ~ liga MX~ Date~18-Febraruary 2006~ full time~0-0

Like this i want to get information for multiple pages of events.

Comment: @sam Your question doesn't ask for all the functionality you want, and what you want to do is much too large of a question for StackOverflow. Beyond matching divs you could match anchor tags with hrefs, but you need to investigate how to parse html in general. I can't write you some simple 10 line solution to parse that page, it's going to be a lot more work than that. Learning to use the library suggested by FSX might be a good start. Good luck.